# asp.net signal r connectionlimit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, signalr

I will try to be as precise as possible:
My scenario is this:
I use an online payment provider on my website (Quickpay in DK). They offer a callback URL in my payment call, which their server will call, when the payment goes through. In their documentation they state that this is the method preferred for having a mandatory answer of the processing of the payment. I also provide a "Continue URL" in my payment call which is called by their payment API, when the payment is processed. They state that this is not supposed to be used as a mandatory answer for updating my order, since the url can be tampered with, more like a way of informing the user. It all makes sense.
Now to my problem with this setup.

A user creates an online payment for a service on my website.
The payment is supplied with the "continue URL", which is hit with parameters i supply.

The asp.net view "Continue URL" is hit, and i start a new connection to a signal r hub. When the connection is started, i spin up an ajax call, which will look in my database if the the callback URL already updated the order. If it is, it shows a div saying "Thanx for your order". But if the payment is not processed yet from the callback URL async. I will not show the "thank you" div, and just wait for the server to connect to my signal r hub, and provide me the answer. This is all to cope with a race condition.
Whenever the Ajax call returns "not updated yet", and I wait for the server, the server will never get connected to the hub. I am pretty sure I am running in to some connection limits.
Here is the client code :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var payment = $.connection.paymentHub;
        payment.client.paymentSuccess = function () {
            $('#paymentSuccess').show();
            $('#paymentWaitingForConfirmation').hide();
        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            payment.server.joinCompany($("#Company_Id").val());
            var data = { companyId: $("#Company_Id").val(), paymentSource: $("#PaymentSource").val()};
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Payment/CheckStatus',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Status === 200) {
                        $('#paymentSuccess').show();
                        $('#paymentWaitingForConfirmation').hide();
                        NProgress.done(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

The callback function calls the hub via this code:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("[my url]");

                        IHubProxy paymentHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PaymentHub");
                        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

                        paymentHubProxy.Invoke("JoinCompany", responseFromPayment.CompanyId.ToString()).Wait();
                        paymentHubProxy.Invoke("PaymentSuccess", responseFromPayment.CompanyId.ToString(),
                            PaymentSource.sms).Wait();
```

I have loglines in between, and the last thing i see in the database is AFTER call to start.
I have a unit test successfully doing the code from the callback, so no issues with this. 
Everything is NADded from the outside via my ip and a URL in DNS, for traffic on port 80, to my local IIS to make it work.
OS is windows 10 IIS 10, signal r version 2.2.0, browser is Chrome Version 48.0.2564.97

I Really hope You guys can help me out.

I added some tracing, this is what i got back. I dont quite understand it:

```
I enabled trace on the connection: this is what i got back:

20:35:37.3524239 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:35:27.3529777 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:35:17.3511832 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:35:07.3518849 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:34:57.3368445 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:34:47.3207855 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {})
20:34:42.9706258 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: {"C":"d-C4BA6FA7-B,0|G,0|H,1","S":1,"M":[]})
20:34:42.9679338 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: OnMessage(Data: initialized)
20:34:42.9614299 - c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca - SSE: GET http://[url]/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionData=[{"Name":"PaymentHub"}]&connectionToken=ZH2%2F1lMBXHDY%2FYwdazoMS5h0VvFvoP6OZrDYOzbc0TFG%2FcEgK7tn9pJnVRPk5OmL%2FCqXxvxDcI4p6dxPKNXg57a%2Fpmtk29Ba2cqJGEREr0ljZjfH0WcBzL1RklBgtCj%2F
20:34:42.9248908 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
```

Comment: Are you able to get a connection to the hub? Does the /Payment/CheckStatus ajax call fire after the hub starts?

Comment: Yes but the connection ID is empty and yes the ajax call is chained to the connect event fired from the connection

Comment: Sorry - it is of course chained to the start event on the hub :  $.connection.hub.start().done(function ()

Comment: if i fire up a url for the "continue URL" for the payment site, and run this unit test:  var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://shop.booktidonline.dk/");
            IHubProxy paymentHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("PaymentHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            paymentHubProxy.Invoke("JoinCompany", "eb294e1e-4776-4c94-b6e4-dac79ae6a134").Wait();
            paymentHubProxy.Invoke("PaymentSuccess", "eb294e1e-4776-4c94-b6e4-dac79ae6a134", PaymentSource.sms);  everything is working

Comment: If the connection succeeds, you should get a GUID for the connection ID. Try adding a `.fail()` statement after the `.done()` statement

Comment: I enabled trace on the connection:

Comment: But it is not suitable for my C# client the javascript client connects gracefully. I have edited my post with the trace info after adding trace to my c# client

Comment: After adding the trace, it seems that you have a connection `c33fab7f-f4fa-44c9-9443-51384e4606ca` and receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that you are deadlocking yourself because you are using `.Wait();`. Make your method async and use `await` instead. See details [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: There is no difference using async and await. I cant see how I am dealocking myself. This is from a callback thread not on the asp.net thread. the wait() would just make the code serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just throwing this out there because the Title of this question seems to be asking about the connection limit. See the section on the concurrent limit.
http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/SignalR/How-to-improve-Signalr-performance/20303